# Can't do GET request for pull subscription from local fake PubSub Server

Tags: get, postman, gcloud, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

**TL;DR: What is the correct way to send a GET Request to do a pull subscription from a Pub/Sub server. What is the correct URL to use?**

I am running a local Google Pub/Sub fake using `gcloud beta emulators pubsub start`, I have been able to successfully publish to it using a ruby script I wrote, however I have been unable to do a pull subscription.

I am aiming to accomplish this just using a GET request, not a script. One of the issues I've found is there's [tons](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-ruby/tree/master/google-cloud-pubsub) of [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/emulator) on doing [pull subscriptions](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/pull#ruby) with a client or [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/pubsub/subscriptions/pull), but very little on how to access the server by URL. Perhaps I am misunderstanding what is possible - *but I want to publish a message to pub/sub using a ruby client, and then use Postman to do a GET request to the pub/sub server to retrieve the message.*

**I am fairly certain the issue is with how I am making a get request, but I have reproduced everything else below for context**

Ruby Publishing Code

```
require "google/cloud/pubsub"
require 'json'

class Publisher
    def publish(event)

        puts "1==============>>>>>>>> publishing..."
        pubsub = Google::Cloud::PubSub.new(
            project_id: "grpc-demo-proj",
            emulator_host: "localhost:8085"
        )

        topic_id = "event_topic"
        topic = pubsub.topic topic_id

        begin
            topic.publish_async "receive_event#event",
                    event: JSON.generate(event) do |result|
                raise "Failed to publish the message." unless result.succeeded?
                puts "2==============>>>>>>>>  Message published asynchronously."
            end

            # Stop the async_publisher to send all queued messages immediately.
            topic.async_publisher.stop.wait!
            rescue StandardError => e
            puts "3==============>>>>>>>> Received error while publishing: #{e.message}"
        end
    end
end
```

This seems to work, as I get

```
1==============>>>>>>>> publishing...
DEBUG  GRPC : calling localhost:8085:/google.pubsub.v1.Publisher/GetTopic
DEBUG  GRPC : calling localhost:8085:/google.pubsub.v1.Publisher/Publish
2==============>>>>>>>>  Message published asynchronously.
```

In my terminal.

I also have the Pub/Sub server running using the following shell scripts.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Kill the existing process if it's already running
if [ "$(lsof -i:8085)" ]; then
  kill $(lsof -t -i:8085)
fi

# Kick off the new process
gcloud beta emulators pubsub start --project=grpc-demo-proj

# Connect to environment variables
$(gcloud beta emulators pubsub env-init)
```

PubSub Setup Script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Wait for the pubsub emulator to boot up
sleep 7
while [[ ! "$(lsof -i:8085)" ]]
do
  echo '#===> PUBSUB EMULATOR SETUP: Waiting for PubSub Emulator to start...'
  sleep 3
done

  # Create topics
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request PUT \
  http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/grpc-demo-proj/topics/event_topic


# Create test subscriptions for each topic
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request PUT \
  --data '{"topic": "projects/grpc-demo-proj/topics/event_topic"}' \
  http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/grpc-demo-proj/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1
```

Again. These seem to work well.

**Where I have trouble...**
is doing a pull subscription from the pub/sub server using a GET request (Either from PostMan, or just in browser's URL bar)

```
http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/grpc-demo-proj/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1:pull
```

Returns

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid [subscriptions] name: (name=projects/grpc-demo-proj/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1:pull)",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
}
```

But the subscription name is valid, as

```
http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/grpc-demo-proj/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1
```

returns

```
{
    "name": "projects/grpc-demo-proj/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1",
    "topic": "projects/grpc-demo-proj/topics/event_topic",
    "pushConfig": {},
    "ackDeadlineSeconds": 10,
    "messageRetentionDuration": "604800s"
}
```

Which would seem to confirm the server is working, and the topics and subscriptions have been successfully created.

Although -NOT- the solution I am looking for, I tried using gcloud in command line:

```
bgc@jadzia:~$ gcloud beta pubsub subscriptions pull test_sub1
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.pubsub.subscriptions.pull) NOT_FOUND: Resource not found (resource=test_sub1).
```

Even though other sources seem to confirm this subscription *does* exist.

While it could possibly be an issue with Ruby incorrectly saying it successfully published the message, or something is wrong with the server. I suspect I'm just not doing the GET request correctly. I've tried several variations on the above GET request but won't list them all here.

So, without using a script - how can I get a message back from the pub/sub server? Ideally a URL for a GET request I can plug into PostMan, but command-line based solutions may also work here.

Comment: Admittedly (apologies) only briefly scanned your question. Here's the REST (PUT) method for creating subscriptions: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create

Comment: Here's Goggle's (recommended) Ruby SDK for Pub/Sub: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/quickstart-client-libraries#pubsub-client-libraries-ruby

Comment: I have already created a subscription, I have trouble trying to get a message from one. I am also not looking to use Ruby SDK for this, I only am using it for publishing.

Comment: That said, a diff page in your first link looked promising: https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull - I tried the HTTP request it mentions. It is the same URL as the one I tried in my question but as a POST request, not a GET request. Unfortunately, it still does not work, giving a 404 and "Subscription does not exist", even though running the curl command in the setups script again to create a subscription again gives "ALREADY_EXISTS: Subscription already exists". So it does not exist but also it does.

Schrodinger's Pub/Sub Subscription?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did reproduce your local fake Pub/sub server using the all the scripts you posted. As you commented I used POST instead of GET and got a response. [Pub/Sub subscriptions pull reference](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/pull)

> POST [https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/{subscription}:pull](https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/%7Bsubscription%7D:pull)

POST request for subscriptions pull:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
--data "{
  "maxMessages": "1"
}" \
http://localhost:8085/v1/projects/my-project/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1:pull
```

Output of subscriptions pull:
[image]

[Pubsub Message](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/PubsubMessage) is encoded in base 64. Take note that I ran everything (creation of pubsub server, topics, subscriber, publish of message, pulling of message) in the Google cloud shell.

**EDIT 1:**

As Brian mentioned, this is the request that is working for him. This works on my testing as well!

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--request POST \
localhost:8085/v1/projects/my-prject/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1:pull?maxMessages=5
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, looks like I am doing the right things, at least in theory. I tried that curl command instead of using PostMan, but get the same result "Subscription Does Not Exist".

Comment: I am unsure how to confirm my message is encoded in base 64, but I am not sure that would be causing this error. I imagine it would have failed to publish were that the case.

Comment: Ok. SOLVED! The subscription issue was because I needed to specify {topic}.{subscription}:pull at the end, not just {subscription}.pull. Also - there is a required parameter, maxMessages, that is not that obvious. Working request was:

`POST localhost:8085/v1/projects/grpc-demo-proj/subscriptions/event_topic.test_sub1:pull?maxMessages=5`

Comment: If you want to edit your answer accordingly i will happily accept it

Comment: @BrianC Sure, let me test this as well. As it is a more efficient way to write a POST request!

Comment: sorry it took like 2 years but finally accepted it